Ramanujan's formula in Iwaniec and Kowalski Chapter 1
In Iwaniec and Kowalski's Analytic Number Theory Chapter 1 (p. 14), they stated without proof the following Ramanujan's formula
$$\zeta(s) \zeta(s - \alpha) \zeta( s - \beta) \zeta(s - \alpha - \beta) \zeta^{-1}(2s - \alpha - \beta) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_\alpha(n) \sigma_\beta(n) n^{-1}.$$
How do I prove this?
Also by specializing to $\alpha = \beta = 0$, they derive
$$\zeta^4(s) \zeta^{-1}(2s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau(n)^2 n^{-s}.$$
This is obvious since $\sigma_0(n) = \sum_{d |n} d^0 = \tau(n)$.
But then they mention dividing both sides of the above by $\zeta(s)$, one gets
$$\zeta^3(s) \zeta^{-1}(2s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau(n^2) n^{-s}.$$
I fail to see the last identity. It seems I need to prove
$$\sum_{d|n} \mu(\frac{n}{d}) \tau(d)^2 = \tau(n^2),$$
or alternatively,
$$ \sum_{d|n} \tau(d^2) = \tau(n)^2.$$
The only way I know is to prove the latter by verifying it on prime powers $n = p^k$, then invoke multiplicativity of $n \mapsto \tau(n)^2$, $n \mapsto \tau(n^2)$ and $n \mapsto 1$ and Dirichlet convolution. Is there a more straightforward way?
